# Angular 2 assets per environment

Tags: angular, assets, environment

I know how to setup environments but i can't figure out how to use a different set of assets (logos/icons) per environment.

I could just overwrite the complete assets dir after a build with an other one but that would be to easy.

Can this even be done?

Comment: Maybe if you fork the cli and implement it yourself. I don't think it's possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible. But you could put the name of the logos/icons as variable to i.e. environment.prod.ts or environement.dev.ts (logo-prod.jpg/logo-dev.jpg) and use that variable in the templates. Then the value of the variable depends on the build target. In the assets then you have to keep both versions of the logo.

Comment: That was my first idea, the problem with that is that you cannot change the assets that live inside the header this way, like "shortcut icon", "favicon" etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently on Angular 7, so I'm not sure how far back this will work. But I used the `fileReplacements` section of the build configuration in `angular.json` to replace my icon at build time.
https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#build-configs

```
      "configurations": {
        "staging": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
            },
            {
              "replace": "src/assets/icon/favicon.ico",
              "with": "src/assets/icon/favicon.staging.ico"
            }
          ]
        },
```